# Setting table AutoFit via VBA gives different result than clicking UI button

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I'm trying to set AutoFitBehavior of a Word table to fit both content and window - clicking 'AutoFit Contents' button, then 'AutoFit Window' gives the result I want to get. The problem is, when I do this using VBA, the formatting is different. Interestingly enough, when I run the macro Step By Step (F8) it gives expected result (same as UI).

Here's my code:

```
Documents(1).Activate
With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
    .AllowAutoFit = True
    .AutoFitBehavior 1
    .AutoFitBehavior 2
End With
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple - I can't find any reason for it to work incorrectly.

Also I don't think the issue is related to using 'ActiveDocument' property, as in the full macro this code is executed directly on a newly created, named document, so I'm sure it's addressing a correct table in a correct file.

I am aware that I can set column widths with PreferredWidth property, but it would be much simpler to use AutoFit, as I don't always know what length will my data have.

Is there a way to make this method work as when called from UI?

---

**Edit:**
As per Cindy Meister's request, I'm adding snippet from actual code I'm using:

```
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(strPath)

With wordDoc
    .Tables.Add Range:=wordDoc.Bookmarks("tableBookmark").Range, NumRows:=licenceRows, NumColumns:=3

    '[omitted: populating the table]

    .Tables(1).Split(splitRow)
    With .Tables(2)
        .Range.Collapse Direction:=0
        .Range.InsertBreak Type:=7
        .AllowAutoFit = True
        .AutoFitBehavior 1
        .AutoFitBehavior 2
    End With
End With
```

It's called from an Excel macro I'm using to create a report file from template. I'm using Office 2013.

Also I've noticed another thing today: when I set `wordApp.Visible = True`, scroll to the table and literally look at the method working - it formats correctly. It's like Word application won't use this method correctly, until it *has to* show you every single step (as with step-by-step run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Cindy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48912445/9385309) and following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884982/setting-table-autofit-via-vba-gives-different-result-than-clicking-ui-button#comment84864697_48912445) I realised my mistake - I thought Auto Fit would make columns fit to any text, including text with line-breaking characters like spaces. Comes out it doesn't work that way.

In the end, to format the table as I wanted (window-wide table, columns fit to content) I used the following code:

```
'Table should fit the page and fit the contents
Sub TestFormatTableStructure()
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim tbl1 As Word.Table, tbl2 As Word.Table

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set wordApp = New Word.Application
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

wordApp.ScreenUpdating = False

With wordDoc
    Set tbl1 = .Tables.Add(Range:=wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range, _
               NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=3, _
               DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
               AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitContent) 'autofit content
    With tbl1
        '[omitted: populating the table]
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
        .PreferredWidth = 100
    End With

    Set tbl2 = tbl1.Split(4)
    'dont have to set formatting again for second table, its inherited
    With tbl2
        '[do things]
    End With
End With

ErrHandler:
    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set tbl1 = Nothing
    Set tbl2 = Nothing
    Set rngtlb = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional info. For the future, in such a case it would help if you include the automation code for running from Excel, as well, since the issue could be with that interface...

I ran the following code in Office 2013 (as well as in 2010) and it worked as expected: the table fit the width of the page (margin to margin) and the cells expanded to fit the content.

In contrast to what you have, I've used the optional arguments in Tables.Add to set the default behavior to allow AutoFit when creating the table. Then I didn't need to set all of them after-the-fact.

Notice also my use of object variables for the tables and the Ranges, releasing the objects, and updating the screen.

```
'Table should fit the page and fit the contents
Sub TestFormatTableStructure()
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim tbl1 As Word.Table, tbl2 As Word.Table
    Dim rngTbl As Word.Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

    wordApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wordDoc
        Set tbl1 = .Tables.Add(Range:=wordDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range, _
                   NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=3, _
                   DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                   AutoFitBehavior:=2)

    '[omitted: populating the table]

    Set tbl2 = tbl1.Split(4)
        With tbl2
            Set rngTbl = .Range
            rngTbl.Collapse Direction:=0
            rngTbl.InsertBreak Type:=7
            '.AllowAutoFit = True
            '.AutoFitBehavior 1
            .AutoFitBehavior 2
        End With
    End With

ErrHandler:
    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set tbl1 = Nothing
    Set tbl2 = Nothing
    Set rngtlb = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesnt't work for me, shows window-width tables with even column widths, no matter how long the contents are. I think you might have made a mistake, as you have used value 2 (wdAutoFitWindow) twice? Though I tried every one of the four possible combinations and none of them worked as I wanted, haha.

Comment: @MałgorzataDurak Believe me: I tested the code thoroughly before posting. When I typed in a cell (2nd column) *with no spaces* that column gets wider to accomodate the text. What wiil *not* happen is that the cell gets wider for just any text - the text may not contain something Word normally uses to break to a new line. This is by design.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure you wouldn't post untested code, just thought you've made a typo. Thanks for the clarification - actually, that's what I was trying to do, make the columns fit text with spaces. I thought using `.AutoFitBehavior` would work like that, cause GUI 'AutoFit Window' button expanded columns as I wanted them to be. Guess that's just some side effect of the button though. Your code works as you said, so I'm accepting your answer, even if it's not a solution to my actual problem (which I actually solved by using `wdAutoFitContent` and `.PreferredWith = 100`).

Comment: @MałgorzataDurak If what you found is better for you, post it as an Answer and mark it as such (once the site allows you to) :-) It's a pretty fair bet that someone else will want to do the same, sometime in the future, and will be happy you have done so. If you think my contribution is "useful" you can use the upvote button (triangle) even if it isn't marked as "the" answer. Good detective work, by the way!

Comment: Okay, I'm going to do that :) Thanks again for all of your help!